# Issue with using textract.process to extract text using the pdfminer method

Tags: python-3.x, text-extraction, pdfminer

Here is the code from the Jupyter notebook that takes the pdf files in the data folder, and extracts the text using the line `text = textract.process(pdf_path, method='pdfminer')`.

```
tokenizer = tiktoken.get_encoding("cl100k_base")

# Process each PDF file and prepare for embedding
for pdf_file in pdf_files:    
    pdf_path = os.path.join(data_dir,pdf_file)
    print(pdf_path)
    
    # # Extract the raw text from each PDF using textract
    text = textract.process(pdf_path, method='pdfminer')
```

I'm getting the following stack trace as a result, it seems like the filename isn't getting passed properly at some point during this process. I've spent several hours looking at this and haven't made any progress:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\pdf_parser.py:54, in Parser.extract_pdfminer(self, filename, **kwargs)
     53 try:
---> 54     stdout, _ = self.run(['pdf2txt.py', filename])
     55 except OSError:

File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\utils.py:87, in ShellParser.run(self, args)
     86 try:
---> 87     pipe = subprocess.Popen(
     88         args,
     89         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
     90     )
     91 except OSError as e:

File c:\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py:1024, in Popen.__init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask, pipesize, process_group)
   1021             self.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(self.stderr,
   1022                     encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
-> 1024     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
   1025                         pass_fds, cwd, env,
   1026                         startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
   1027                         p2cread, p2cwrite,
   1028                         c2pread, c2pwrite,
   1029                         errread, errwrite,
   1030                         restore_signals,
   1031                         gid, gids, uid, umask,
   1032                         start_new_session, process_group)
   1033 except:
   1034     # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

File c:\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py:1493, in Popen._execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_gid, unused_gids, unused_uid, unused_umask, unused_start_new_session, unused_process_group)
   1492 try:
-> 1493     hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
   1494                              # no special security
   1495                              None, None,
   1496                              int(not close_fds),
   1497                              creationflags,
   1498                              env,
   1499                              cwd,
   1500                              startupinfo)
   1501 finally:
   1502     # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe
   1503     # handles that only the child should have open.  You need
   (...)
   1506     # pipe will not close when the child process exits and the
   1507     # ReadFile will hang.

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File :12

File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\__init__.py:79, in process(filename, input_encoding, output_encoding, extension, **kwargs)
     76 # do the extraction
     78 parser = filetype_module.Parser()
---> 79 return parser.process(filename, input_encoding, output_encoding, **kwargs)

File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\utils.py:46, in BaseParser.process(self, filename, input_encoding, output_encoding, **kwargs)
     36 """Process ``filename`` and encode byte-string with ``encoding``. This
     37 method is called by :func:`textract.parsers.process` and wraps
     38 the :meth:`.BaseParser.extract` method in `a delicious unicode
     39 sandwich `_.
     40 
     41 """
     42 # make a "unicode sandwich" to handle dealing with unknown
     43 # input byte strings and converting them to a predictable
     44 # output encoding
     45 # http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain/unipain.html#35
---> 46 byte_string = self.extract(filename, **kwargs)
     47 unicode_string = self.decode(byte_string, input_encoding)
     48 return self.encode(unicode_string, output_encoding)

File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\pdf_parser.py:32, in Parser.extract(self, filename, method, **kwargs)
     29             raise ex
     31 elif method == 'pdfminer':
---> 32     return self.extract_pdfminer(filename, **kwargs)
     33 elif method == 'tesseract':
     34     return self.extract_tesseract(filename, **kwargs)

File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\pdf_parser.py:57, in Parser.extract_pdfminer(self, filename, **kwargs)
     55 except OSError:
     56     try:
---> 57         stdout, _ = self.run(['python3',pdf2txt_path, filename])
     58     except ShellError:
     59         stdout, _ = self.run(['python2',pdf2txt_path, filename])

File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\utils.py:87, in ShellParser.run(self, args)
     85 # run a subprocess and put the stdout and stderr on the pipe object
     86 try:
---> 87     pipe = subprocess.Popen(
     88         args,
     89         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
     90     )
     91 except OSError as e:
     92     if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
     93         # File not found.
     94         # This is equivalent to getting exitcode 127 from sh

File c:\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py:1024, in Popen.__init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask, pipesize, process_group)
   1020         if self.text_mode:
   1021             self.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(self.stderr,
   1022                     encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
-> 1024     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
   1025                         pass_fds, cwd, env,
   1026                         startupinfo, creationflags, shell,
   1027                         p2cread, p2cwrite,
   1028                         c2pread, c2pwrite,
   1029                         errread, errwrite,
   1030                         restore_signals,
   1031                         gid, gids, uid, umask,
   1032                         start_new_session, process_group)
   1033 except:
   1034     # Cleanup if the child failed starting.
   1035     for f in filter(None, (self.stdin, self.stdout, self.stderr)):

File c:\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py:1433, in Popen._execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_gid, unused_gids, unused_uid, unused_umask, unused_start_new_session, unused_process_group)
   1431     args = list2cmdline([args])
   1432 else:
-> 1433     args = list2cmdline(args)
   1435 if executable is not None:
   1436     executable = os.fsdecode(executable)

File c:\Python311\Lib\subprocess.py:608, in list2cmdline(seq)
    606 result = []
    607 needquote = False
--> 608 for arg in map(os.fsdecode, seq):
    609     bs_buf = []
    611     # Add a space to separate this argument from the others

File :824, in fsdecode(filename)

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

I've mostly tried experimenting with the input into `textract.process(pdf_path, method='pdfminer')`

The first thing I noticed is that the pdf_path had '.\' in front of the path, so I tried the following input `textract.process('data\\' + pdf_file, method='pdfminer')`, but ended up with the same error.

I also tried just passing in the pdf_file like so `textract.process(pdf_file, method='pdfminer')`, but got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MissingFileError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
File :12

File c:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\textract\parsers\__init__.py:41, in process(filename, input_encoding, output_encoding, extension, **kwargs)
     39 # make sure the filename exists
     40 if not os.path.exists(filename):
---> 41     raise exceptions.MissingFileError(filename)
     43 # get the filename extension, which is something like .docx for
     44 # example, and import the module dynamically using importlib. This
     45 # is a relative import so the name of the package is necessary
     46 # normally, file extension will be extracted from the file name
     47 # if the file name has no extension, then the user can pass the
     48 # extension as an argument
     49 if extension:

MissingFileError: The file "f1040.pdf" can not be found.
Is this the right path/to/file/you/want/to/extract.pdf?
```

I've also tried to add additional PDF files to the data folder to check to see if the issue had something to do with the fact that I was using one file, I've also tried changing the PDF file names to see if the issue had to do with the name of the file.